# how to show in menu my recently files in visual basic 6

Tags: vb6

I have a program in vb6, and i want to view recently opened files in menu. I got no ideea how to do it, please somebody help, i'll provide the code:

```
Option Explicit

Dim Dates(1000) As Date
Dim Weights(1000) As String
Dim NumWts As Integer

Sub Init()
  NumWts = 1: vsbControl.Value = 1: vsbControl.Max = 1
  Dates(1) = Format(Now, "mm/dd/yy")
  Weights(1) = ""
  lblDate.Caption = Dates(1)
  txtWeight.Text = Weights(1)
  lblFile.Caption = "New File"
End Sub

Private Sub Form_Load()
  frmWeight.Show
  Call Init
End Sub

Private Sub mnuFileExit_Click()
  'Make sure user really wants to exit
  Dim Response As Integer
  Response = MsgBox("Are you sure you want to exit the Weight Program?", _
  vbYesNo + vbCritical + vbDefaultButton2, "Exit Editor")
  If Response = vbNo Then
    Exit Sub
  Else
    End
  End If
End Sub

Private Sub mnuFileNew_Click()
  'User wants new file
  Dim Response As Integer
  Response = MsgBox("Are you sure you want to start a new file?", _
  vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "New File")
  If Response = vbNo Then
    Exit Sub
  Else
    Call Init
  End If
End Sub

Private Sub mnuFileOpen_Click()
  Dim I As Integer
  Dim Today As Date
  Dim Response As Integer
  Response = MsgBox("Are you sure you want to open a new file?", _
  vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "New File")
  If Response = vbNo Then Exit Sub
  cdlFiles.Filter = "Files (.wgt)|.wgt"
  cdlFiles.DefaultExt = "wgt"
  cdlFiles.DialogTitle = "Open File"
  cdlFiles.Flags = cdlOFNFileMustExist + cdlOFNPathMustExist
  On Error GoTo No_Open
  cdlFiles.ShowOpen
  Open cdlFiles.FileName For Input As #1
    lblFile.Caption = cdlFiles.FileName
    Input #1, NumWts
    For I = 1 To NumWts
      Input #1, Dates(I), Weights(I)
    Next I
  Close 1
  Today = Format(Now, "mm/dd/yy")
  If Today <> Dates(NumWts) Then
    NumWts = NumWts + 1
    Dates(NumWts) = Today
    Weights(NumWts) = ""
  End If
  vsbControl.Max = NumWts
  vsbControl.Value = NumWts
  lblDate.Caption = Dates(NumWts)
  txtWeight.Text = Weights(NumWts)
  Exit Sub
No_Open:
  Resume ExitLine
ExitLine:
  Exit Sub
End Sub

Private Sub mnuFileSave_Click()
  Dim I As Integer
  cdlFiles.Filter = "Files (.wgt)|.wgt"
  cdlFiles.DefaultExt = "wgt"
  cdlFiles.DialogTitle = "Save File"
  cdlFiles.Flags = cdlOFNOverwritePrompt + cdlOFNPathMustExist
  On Error GoTo No_Save
  cdlFiles.ShowSave
  Open cdlFiles.FileName For Output As #1
    lblFile.Caption = cdlFiles.FileName
    Write #1, NumWts
    For I = 1 To NumWts
      Write #1, Dates(I), Weights(I)
    Next I
  Close 1
  Exit Sub
No_Save:
  Resume ExitLine
ExitLine:
  Exit Sub
End Sub

Private Sub txtWeight_Change()
  Weights(vsbControl.Value) = txtWeight.Text
End Sub

Private Sub txtWeight_KeyPress(KeyAscii As Integer)
  If KeyAscii >= vbKey0 And KeyAscii <= vbKey9 Then
    Exit Sub
  Else
    KeyAscii = 0
  End If
End Sub

Private Sub vsbControl_Change()
  lblDate.Caption = Dates(vsbControl.Value)
  txtWeight.Text = Weights(vsbControl.Value)
  txtWeight.SetFocus
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

in your file menus save the filenames to a database or register or xml file or plain text file or anything else

when you want to show the recently opened files read in the filenames you previously saved